# i18n: NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization

Doing tests locally on my computer:

**index.hml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--script src="angular.js"></script-->
        <script src="i18next.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
i18n.init();
```

**Error @ line 672 in i18next.js**

```
xhr.send(payload);
```

> NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied

- How do I solve this error?
- Optional: What does this line do?

Comment: look here if can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340482/ns-error-dom-bad-uri-access-to-restricted-uri-denied/28519760#28519760

Comment: could you specify details of your xhr?

Answer (score 1):

You are encountering a same-origin-policy issue (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). This means that either the port, domain, or protocol is not the same between the URI that you are sending a request TO and the URL that you are sending the request FROM.

You can overcome this by adding headers to your server side code:
`Access-Control-Request-Headers`
`Access-Control-Request-Method`

See: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score -2):

I have resolve NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI error in my project (using ReactJS - handle API by axios) but I think my explaination an solution can help you:

1. How did I get this error:

FE code:

```
headers:  {
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

BE code (Spring Boot):

```
allowedHeaders("userLoginToken", "Content-Type")
```

Because I only allow 'Content-Type' in headers, but my header have redundant config 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and my BE not allow that.

2. How did I resolve:
   Only delete 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in request headers and error was disappeared.

   headers:  {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   }